# Passing an Extra Variable From A Form to a Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a basic setup where from within a Post you can create a Comment. I want to create a POST method that takes a text area and creates a comment with the body from the text area. But my Comment model requires a Post foreign key. Is there any way I can pass the post along with the body without having a hidden form element or something similar? And without using AJAX. Here is my form code:

```
= form_tag(comments_path) do
  = text_field_tag(:body)
  = submit_tag("Submit Answer")
```

Comment: Please copy and paste your Post form code

Comment: Done, but it's super bare bones.

Comment: Its not clear to me, I thought you want to create the comment inside a Post form, isn't that your need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There's the option of using [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)**.  *i.e. put it in the URI.*

```
# routes.rb
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

This will create a few routes, namely `/posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)`

**A form could look like**:

```
form_for Comment.new, url: post_comments_path(post_id: @post), method: :post do |f|
  # ...
```

Though, it will be your controller's responsibility to locate the `Post` from the `params` before saving your `Comment`.

---

**One final note**: this approach is justified only because it's a reference to the parent resource.  Appending any other loose variables to the URI is lazy.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Post.rb`

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
```

In your `PostController.rb`

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
  @post.comments.build
end
```

In your `views/posts/new.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :content %>
  <%= f.text_field :content %>

  <%= f.fields_for :comments do |comment_form| %>
    <%= comment_form.text_field :body %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```